# angular formly template option optional

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Setting up options in angular formly is so far no problem.

The template definition:

```
formlyConfig.setType({
    name: 'myType',
    template: '<div myType ng-model="model[options.key]" theme="to.theme" size="to.size"></div>',
});
```

In the controller I can then call my new `myType`:

```
{
    key: 'myType',
    type: 'myType',
    templateOptions: {
        theme: 'light',
        size: 'normal'
    }
},
```

But now I want to set the template options `theme` and `size` optional, so that they do not have to be written down. A "default" value for both is then set in the `app.config`.

I came up with this:

```
formlyConfig.setType({
    name: 'myType',
    template: '<div myType ng-model="model[options.key]" {{to.theme ? \'theme="to.theme"\' : \'\'}} {{to.size ? \'size="to.size"\' : \'\'}} ></div>',
});
```

But unfortunately this is nor working.

When I delete a option in the controller like this:

```
{
    key: 'myType',
    type: 'myType',
    templateOptions: {
        theme: 'light'
    }
},
```

my default value out of the config is not loaded, except when I also delete the `size` part out of the template like this:

```
formlyConfig.setType({
    name: 'myType',
    template: '<div myType ng-model="model[options.key]" {{to.theme ? \'theme="to.theme"\' : \'\'}} ></div>',
});
```

So I assume that my idea how to set a template option optional is wrong.
But how can I do it?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**
Of course there is also the `ng-attr` from angular. But this is unfortunately also not working as template:

```
<div myType ng-model="model[options.key]" ng-attr-size="to.size || undefined" ></div>
```

or

```
<div myType ng-model="model[options.key]" ng-attr-size="to.size ? to.size : undefined" ></div>
```